# Angular 4 , how to detect or get old after subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

My issue is I created a function  getConferenceDetails

```
this.eventsService.getConferenceEvents().subscribe(events => {
  this.conferenceDetails = events;
  let newCountOfConference = Object.assign({}, events[0]);
  console.log(newCountOfConference);

  if(!(this.user.protected.events && this.user.protected.events.hasOwnProperty("3DPASS2019"))) {
    this.calculateTotal(1, this.conferenceDetails[0]);
  }
  this.showPopupOnPriceChanged();
})}
```

Here inside this.conferenceDetails, I have object like 
`{amount : 2700 , availability :3000}`

I uses a firebase as my backend , if suppose from firebase I changed the object amount value to 2800, then the whole object changed to new value, but I want that previous object value of amount. I want to do some comparison like if amount value changes then do something, issue is I unable to detect what was previous value. Is there any way to get the previous value even after subscribed ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54390556/angular-reset-input-value-to-previous-value/54391225#54391225 This is very similar to what you need here. Just look at the rxjs `pairwise` operator. If you are not able to get this working then I will add the answer. But that should be very easy.

Comment: Excellent , It worked . Thank you very much @AmitChigadani